# Cannot boot: "No init found. Try passing init=bootarg"

Tags: 10.10, boot, fsck

After losing power, my machine rebooted to this error:

> “error: no init found. Try passing init=bootarg”

Per similar threads on this site and others, I've tried booting from a CD and selecting "Try Ubuntu". Then open a terminal and typing:

> sudo fsck-y /dev/sda1.

The response is:

> Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda1. Filesystem
>   mounted or opened exclusively by another program?

This is on Ubuntu 10.10.

Any ideas on what I can try next?

Comment: Try `sudo umount /dev/sda1` from the terminal **in the LiveCD** before running fsck

Comment: umount: /dev/sda1: not mounted

Answer (score 3):

#### Disk Utility from Live CD

1. LiveCD or use a Live USB (your personal preference)
2. Dash -> Disk Utility
3. Mount Volume (try this first, if it mounts skip to #6 otherwise go to #4)
4. Check FileSystem (this will run a check and repair anything it needs to)
5. Mount Volume (second attempt, should work after Filesystem check if it didn't before)
6. Close Disk Utility & Shutdown/Restart your computer.
7. Remove the LiveCD (before shutdown) or the LiveUSB (after shutdown)
8. Restart (may or may not go to GRUB menu, if it does choose the first option).

*Note - steps 4. & 5. are only for if the first Mount Volume attempt fails.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1728611.html

Comment: This won't solve similar problem that caused by misconfig. No offense just warning to who had similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial in the form of a detailed list of what steps to take to solve this problem...as listed by the original poster of the thread but improved by me.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12268329#post12268329

This appears to work on every release of Ubuntu as I did it on 12.04

Answer (score -1):

1.Create Puppy linux Live usb or live cd

2.Boot from live usb and go to console

3.run fsck to fix filesystem

Comment: How is this any different from using Ubuntu live cd?