# My laptop with Linux/ Ubuntu isn't working

Tags: dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot boot: “No init found. Try passing init=bootarg”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169052/cannot-boot-no-init-found-try-passing-init-bootarg)

I have a dell laptop with ubuntu linux. A day I tried to start it up and a black screen just appeared that says:

```
GNU GRUB version1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3

(and these clickable options:)

-Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic 
-Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic (recovery mode) 
-Memory test (memtest86+) 
-Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

When I click the first one, a bunch of text appears like:

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/8396a225... 
failed: invalid argument 
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: no such file or directory 
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: no such file or directory 
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: no such file or directory 
Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init 
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands 
BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5) built-in shell (ash) 
(initramfs)
```

When I enter 'help' a bunch more incomprehensible text appears. Whenever I press the enter key all that pops up is (intetramfs)

If anyone can make rhyme or reason out of this please, please help me out so it can boot up normally and i can be set. If there's some kind of special code I have to type in or something
I know nothing about computers.