# Cannot boot: “No init found. Try passing init=bootarg” standard fix not working

Tags: boot

I'm getting the booting error as per [Cannot boot: "No init found. Try passing init=bootarg"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169052)

I'm run commands in a liveCD terminal

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00638cbf

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *    30801920   241535341   105366711    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       241537022   312580095    35521537    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       241537024   309569535    34016256   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       309571584   312580095     1504256   82  Linux swap / Solaris
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
/dev/sda1: 82 files, 4367/20017 clusters
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda2
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda3
Could this be a zero-length partition?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda4
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda4
Possibly non-existent device?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sda5: clean, 160379/2129920 files, 1067688/8504064 blocks
```

I got the solution from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTH3nJ9OOBM . When I reboot I get the same error. One thing I can think of is that I created a new liveCD, maybe it needs to be the correct version?

What to do/ what more info do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug sounds like a core problem with Ubuntu. It appears that your `init` file is missing or corrupt. There are two ways to solve this problem:

### Option 1

---

You can simply re-install Ubuntu. This is the simplest and most reliable method of solving this problem. It also always works.

If you want to save your data, use a LiveCD in "Trial" mode and copy all important stuff to a
USB drive. You can then install directly from the drive.

### Option 2

---

It is theoretically possible to pull a working `init` executable from a working installation and putting that in your `/sbin` folder. This, however, is rather complicated. You can try doing this:

1. Mount the install drive to the /mnt folder
2. As root, copy the `init` file from `/sbin/init` to `/mnt/sbin/init`.
3. Verify and copy the permissions from the working install to the bad install.
4. Test by rebooting.

You should only do this on functionally identical installs. Meaning, don't use a livecd. Instead, use a spare hard drive.

> Pull out the current laptop hard drive and put it in an external caddy. Put the clean drive into the laptop and install Ubuntu. Then, mount and copy.

Comment: The options 2, isn't it will not be saved to initramfs? I try tho, the copied init gone after restart.